# Single-line output with pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Really basic question but I just couldn't get it to work, currently I have a list, header:

```
    header = [
        'Name', 'EmojiXpress, mil.', 'Instagram, mil.', 'Twitter, mil.'
]
```

I want a final output of:

```
| Name | EmojiXpress, mil. | Instagram, mil. | Twitter, mil. |
```

My current code looks like:

```
for name in header:
    print('|', end='')    

    print(name, end='')

    print('|', end='')
```

But this results in:

```
|Name||EmojiXpress, mil.||Instagram, mil.||Twitter, mil.|
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: If you're doing much of this, there's a decent chance you just want to use a custom dialect with the `csv` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are printing both an opening and a closing pipe for each item. My solution is printing an opening pipe for each item in the loop, and then printing a closing pipe after the loop is over.

Try this..

```
for name in header:
    print(' | ', end='')    
    print(name, end='')
print(' | ')
```

Result:

```
| Name | EmojiXpress, mil. | Instagram, mil. | Twitter, mil. |
```

Comment: Thank you, if I could kiss you right now, I would, thanks a million

Answer (score 4):

```
print(f'| {" | ".join(header)} |')
```

Output:

```
| Name | EmojiXpress, mil. | Instagram, mil. | Twitter, mil. |
```

`join()` will join the elements of a list by the string you specify beforehand. Adding in `f-strings` or formatted strings, we can attach the `|` to the beginning and end of the string as well.

Comment: Thanks for the insight......problem required a loop but I'm definitely saving this answer to my notes, very useful